# How to make a drop-down list? Example Search of Google

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ы</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").keyup(function(){
          $("#search").autocomplete("json.php", {
            delay:10,
            minChars:4,
            maxItemsToShow:3
            }
          );
          }); });
      //?word=" + $("#search-text").val()
</script>
<form action=""><input type="search" id="search"> <input type="submit"></form>
<body>
</html>
```

json.php

```
<?php
echo json_decode($_GET['q']);
```

How do make this code to work? How I can use the file json?
How in php to handle the request and return the result to the autocomplete worked?
Maybe there are better solutions?
The official documentation does not contain the server-side code example!

looked response 200ok. no body. echo json_decode ($ _GET ['q']); error here, the question is where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://sitetesting.kiev.ua/ajax.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.countryName
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to use php for autocomplete? is it more hany to use js than to request repeatedly every after keystroke?

any way you can try this instead

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and in body

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: I need get a data from database/

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along these lines to populate your items array and then check if the value in the field matches any of them.

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

/* Connect to database */

/* Query Database */

$items = array();

/* Loop through results and add them to items array */

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $items[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}

foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        echo "$key|$value\n";
    }
}
```

The code for the search (without the database query bit) is documented at http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

This is of course going to generate the array every time someone types a letter into the input field, thus being very server intensive.

A much better way as described above is to use the availableTags variable and load them via PHP into a javascript variable on load. I would recommend using the PHP json_encode function for this.